# ngOnChanges only trigger when reference of object change

Tags: angular

ngOnChanges() method is called only when the reference of the object is changed by parent component.

so How to detect changes if I only change a key of object, at that time no reference change at @Input, so no changes detect.

Comment: Use [doCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck)

Comment: okay, i'll try it, thanks for instant reply

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194203/4399281

Comment: doCheck is extremely expensive, it is one of the least performant methods you could choose to implement and I would not recommend it. If you are going to be doing a lot of state changes on objects and you want Angulars default change detection to pick up on it you should look into immutableJS.

Comment: I can see immer can help